# How can I learn Integrated information Theory

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling, consciousness, theory-of-mind, study-cognitive-sciences

I'm looking for a syllabus for Integrated Information Theory that could help a non-scientists learn all the fundamental concepts required to fully understand IIT

It looks like it involves statistics, algorithms, and perhaps even some calculus, but I'm not sure what kinds.

I'm looking for a list of papers/ Courses/ subjects/ textbooks that could help me go from a basic understanding of IIT to a full understanding of its mathematical framework (Transition probability matrices,  discrete Markovian dynamical systems, etc).

FYI: My highest level of math was differential calculus, but that was a long time ago, so I would need a refresher on that as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you studied the [Wikipedia article on IIT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory) along with other articles and papers linked to it?